# Sampling from pointwise-product density

Tags: sampling

Let$ p$ and $ q$ be two probability densities a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d $. Assume I know how to generate samples from $ p $ and how to generate samples from $ q $, but I do so without actually being able to evaluate the densities.

How do I algorithmically generate samples from the distribution whose density is $\propto pq $?

Comment: Can you assume a unique mapping from p & q to your new distribution, let's call it u, i.e. (P,Q) maps to U?  Also, do you know that P and Q are independent?

Comment: @Robert I don't understand your first question. As for the second question,  yes I can generate samples from $ p $ and $q $ that are independent from each other

Comment: $p,q$ are random variables or probability density functions?

Comment: they are probability density functions

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm getting closer to understanding what you are asking. Is it helpful to reference [this previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55684/pdf-of-product-of-variables) for the general approach and then for your problem note that if you can sample from the distributions, you can create empirical pdfs for them e.g. take a sample of 10^6 from distribution q to form q_hat and substitute q_hat for q?

Comment: I am given densities, which in your discrete example would correspond to $ p=q=(1/6,...,1/6) $. The corresponding pointwise product density would correspond again to $(1/6,...,1/6) $ as this is the unique distribution on $\{1,...,6\}$ (!, not on a larger state space) that is proportional to $ pq=(1/36,...,1/36)$. I don't understand how your answer connects to this

Comment: Still not there :) The post you linked concerns the PDF of the product of random variables. Note that if $P$ and $Q$ are random variables with densities $p$ and $q$, the density of the variables $PQ$ is not $pq$. Also, PQ doesn't even make sense if the domain of $p$ and $q$ is multi-dimensional